# A Strange conversion from number to string

Tags: javascript

I'm writing with TypeScript and codes are as follows:

```
private initModel = () => {
    let brandGoodId: number;

    const getBrandGoodIdFunction = (window.parent as any).auditDisplay;
    if (getBrandGoodIdFunction) {
        brandGoodId = getBrandGoodIdFunction().brandGoodId;
        console.log('get brandGoodId', brandGoodId);
    } else {
        console.log('window.auditDisplay is undefined!');

        return;
    }

    getDisplayInfosByBgids(brandGoodId).then((displayInfoMap) => {
        const displayInfo: DisplayInfo = (displayInfoMap.get(brandGoodId) as DisplayInfo);

        this.modelInfo = toPopBufferComponent(displayInfo.components[0]);

        this.loadModelMesh();
    });
}
```

I have a variable named `brandGoodId` and it should be a number as what `let brandGoodId: number;` shows.

But When I test the compiled js, it shows up a `string` as follows:
[image]

So what happened after compiling? I guess it's babel problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably not related to compilation, but on a runtime value.
Typescript can only check on compile time what should be a value of a variable, but in your example, `brandGoodId` got his value at **runtime** from a function on `window`, and probably that function returns a **string**.

On compile time, you instructed TS to trust you by using `as any` and therefore TS can't assure the return value of the `window.auditDisplay`.

Comment: Well I checked the compiled js and found I have made a mistake that assume declaration like "let brandGoodId: number " will compile to something that keeps "brandGoodId " as a number. Indeed it doesn't do any type check at all